# Devise's current_user's availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

where all is devise's `current_user` method is available? Models? Controllers? Views? Helpers?

I have a `Question` model which belongs to `User`. So while saving new `Question` what is the best way to store `user_id` in `Question`?

`QuestionsController` as of now

```
def create
 @question = Question.create(params[:question])
 @question.save
 render text: "Question created!"
end
```

Comment: can you show us what do you have in your controller right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, and assuming that you have a `has_many` relationship, I would say that the best way to create a question for a user would be something like this:

```
@question = current_user.questions.create(params[:question])
```

Also, `create` is already calling `save`. If you want to manually call it you should use `current_user.questions.build`.